# Загрузка файла в форму post запросом

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста, существует на странице форма, которая принимает файл. Мне нужно загрузить файл через эту форму  .
У меня есть адрес страницы, куки после авторизации  .

В заголовках запроса(смотрел в консоле браузера) есть следуйщие параметры:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarySM5d7XYS2AzlAVLv  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload[uploadFile]"  


------WebKitFormBoundarySM5d7XYS2AzlAVLv  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload[uploadFile]"; filename=""  
Content-Type: application/octet-stream  


------WebKitFormBoundarySM5d7XYS2AzlAVLv    
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="yt0"  

Загрузить
------WebKitFormBoundarySM5d7XYS2AzlAVLv--
```

Не могу правильно сформировать запрос  .

Код html страницы:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file-upload-importWln-form" action="/backend/units/importWln/id/43656" method="post">

    <div class="row">
        <label for="fileUpload_uploadFile">Загрузить файл</label>       
        <input id="ytfileUpload_uploadFile" type="hidden" value="" name="fileUpload[uploadFile]">
        <input name="fileUpload[uploadFile]" id="fileUpload_uploadFile" type="file">            
  </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="yt0" value="Загрузить">   
   </div>
</form>
```

Использовал такой код:

```
var client = new RestClient(tempUrl);
client.CookieContainer = cookie;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);


request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("name", "fileUpload[uploadFile]");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x"));
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary"+ DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x") + ", ------WebKitFormBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x") + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\"; filename=\"" + file + "\"\r\nContent-Type: false\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x"), ParameterType.RequestBody);

request.AddFile("filename", File.ReadAllBytes(file), getOnlyName(file));

request.AddParameter("boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x") + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"yt0\"" + "Загрузить" + ", ------WebKitFormBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x"), ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string rep1 = response.ToString();
```

Comment: Я предлагаю использовать [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), после успешнего отправление файла вы можете скопировать код с Postmana для отправки файла. Понадобиться Restsharp

Comment: @Ikram Turgunbaev А как мне параметры задать? Так и писать в headers: key = Content-Disposition; 
value: form-data; name="fileUpload[uploadFile]"; filename=""
Или form-data, name and filename тоже надо писать как отдельный key?

Comment: В rest запрос нельзя передавать двоичные данные в явном виде. Вы путаете multipart и REST.

Comment: Посмотрите аналогичный вопрос на enSO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload там есть верные ответы

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю использовать [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), после успешнего отправление файла вы можете скопировать код с Postmana для отправки файла. Понадобиться Restsharp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Код запроса взял из Postmana, но пока нет возможности его проверить, отправится файл или нет. А так, большое вам спасибо!